# Bastion main menu invisible

Tags: games, logo

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04.

When I try to play [Bastion](http://supergiantgames.com/?page_id=242), I ran into a problem. The screen shows the Warner Bros logo, then Supergiant games, and then the music starts and the cursor appears, then nothing showed up. I moved the cursor around and it makes click-clack noises as it moves over what I'm guessing are tiles on the menu, so it seems the menu is there, just invisible.

Answer (score 1):

A missing proprietary Graphics card driver may be missing.

Search for "jockey" in the Dash, then open Additional Drivers.  Find your Graphics card driver (AMD/ATI or nVIDIA) and install it.

[image]

Comment: I don't have a graphic card...):

Comment: Every computers have a graphics card.  Does yours say nVIDIA?

Comment: Mine is integrated. It is the intel core 2 duo processor.

Comment: Oops, forgot about that.  If you don't have one, then try Updating your software.

Comment: The answer below says the same thing...

Comment: Tried that and nothing. Man, this is concerning me... I got bastion to work when this computer was running windows, so I know it meets the minimum requirements.

Comment: Well I guess the only way is to reinstall Bastion on your computer.

Comment: I tried that. No luck.

Comment: When I read the answer below: Did you updated using sudo apt-get update?  That only updates the LIST.  Update it using Update-Manager.

Comment: Yeah I just commented below; it told me it can't download repository information.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem a while ago. But an update fixed it for me. Try updating your software via the Updates app.

Comment: Just to be sure, do you mean sudo apt-get update?

Comment: No, just a regular Software Center update in my case. But it is strictly equivalent to apt-get update.

Comment: Updating with Software Centre is equivalent to `apt-get update ; apt-get upgrade`. [See man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/apt-get).

Comment: No luck. I got this too: W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found  

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/chromium-daily/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

W: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/mefrio-g/plymouthmanager/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found               ...etc the list goes on....

Comment: Ok, I just ran the graphical equivalent and got the message that the repos won't update.

Answer (score 0):

I've found a way maybe: https://gist.github.com/3068948

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
#put it in your bastion install folder
#mine is /usr/local/games/Bastion
#bastion ubuntu intel
export force_s3tc_enable=true
./Bastion.bin.x86_64
```